# MVC words limit

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I would like to count the words in the text area instead of each individual character.

Model Class

```
  [RegularExpression(@"[^<>]*", ErrorMessage = "Invalid entry"), StringLength(200)]
        public string Day1Journal { get; set; }
```

HTML

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.StudentJournaldtls.Day1Journal, IsReadOnly == true || IsSubmitted == true ? (object)new { col = 2, @class = "CharacterLimit required", @maxlength = 200, @readonly = "readonly" } : new { col = 2, @class = "CharacterLimit required", @maxlength = 200 })
                            <small>No of characters left:<span class="charsLeft"></span></small>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

$(".CharacterLimit").each(function (i, t) {
    var charsLeft = $(this).attr("maxlength") - $(this).val().split(' ').length
    $(this).parent().find(".charsLeft").text(charsLeft);
});

$(".CharacterLimit").keyup(function (e) {
    var charsLeft = $(this).attr("maxlength") - $(this).val().split(' ').length
    $(this).parent().find(".charsLeft").text(charsLeft);
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get the words count in the text by spliting the value by white spaces, like:

```
$("textbox").val().split(' ').length
```

Comment: Hi, i was able to get the words count. But the words limit still stops at 200 character.